# review count/page

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

[image]

i want to add page on reviews[image]
and dispaly the count of reviews after the rating.How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you want to display the review count of product try this.

`<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short')?>`